# 端末によってアニメーションが動かない

Tags: android

現在`drawable-hdpi`、`drawable-xhdpi`、`drawable-xxhdpi`フォルダにそれぞれサイズの異なる画像を置いています。そしてアニメーションを行うのですが、なぜか`xxhdpi`の端末のみアニメーションが動作し、`xhdpi`の端末は一枚画像が表示されるだけで、`hdpi`の端末に至っては画像すら表示されません。なぜなのでしょうか？下記にコードを記します。すみませんが、どなたか分かる方がいればよろしくお願いします。

MainActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);

        animationImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.animation_imageview);
        animationImageView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (getIntent().getStringExtra("animType").equals("normal_animation")) {
                    AnimationConfig animationConfig = new AnimationConfig(activity, activity);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationData(animationImageView, 2000, 2000, 50);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_01);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_02);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_03);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_04);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_05);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_06);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_07);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_08);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_09);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_10);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_11);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_12);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_13);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_14);
                    animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_15);
                    animationConfig.startAnimation();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

AnimationConfig

```
public class AnimationConfig {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private Context mContext;
    private int mDuration;
    private int mOffset;
    private int mEachImageShowTime;
    private AnimationSet mAnimationSet;
    private ImageView mAnimationImageView;
    private List<Drawable> mFrameList = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

    public AnimationConfig(Activity activity, Context context) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void setAnimationFrame(int image) {
        mFrameList.add(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(image));
    }

    public void setAnimationData(ImageView imageView, int duration, int offset, int eachImageShowTime) {
        mAnimationImageView = imageView;
        mDuration = duration;
        mOffset = offset;
        mEachImageShowTime = eachImageShowTime;
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        setFrameAnimation(mAnimationImageView, mEachImageShowTime);
        mAnimationImageView.startAnimation(setFadeAnimation(mDuration, mOffset));
    }

    public AnimationSet setFadeAnimation(int duration, final int offset){
        AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        final AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeIn.setDuration(duration);

        fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                fadeOut.setStartOffset(offset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        fadeOut.setDuration(duration);
        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mAnimationImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAnimationSet.setFillAfter(true);
                screenTransition();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        mAnimationSet = new android.view.animation.AnimationSet(false); {
            mAnimationSet.addAnimation(fadeIn);
            mAnimationSet.addAnimation(fadeOut);
        }

        return mAnimationSet;
    }

    public void setFrameAnimation(ImageView imageView, int sec) {
        mAnimationImageView = imageView;
        AnimationDrawable anim = new AnimationDrawable();
        for (Drawable frame:mFrameList) {
            anim.addFrame(frame, sec);
        }
        anim.setOneShot(false);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(anim);
    }
}
```

Comment: `AnimationDrawable#start()`をそもそも呼び出してないのは問題ないんでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。AnimationDrawable#start()を呼ぶことで、他の端末でもアニメーションを動かすことができました！しかし、なぜxxhdpiの端末ではアニメーションが動いたのでしょうか？アニメーションが動いた端末はNexus5です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

表題に対する回答としては、`AnimationDrawable#start()`が呼び出されていない、になります。

では、なぜ端末によっては`AnimationDrawable`が自動的に再生されるのでしょう？これは端末密度による違いではなく、単に一部のバージョンのバグと思われます。

特定のバージョン以降、`setImageDrawable()`で渡された`Drawable`は、`Drawable#setVisible(true, true)`が呼び出されるのようになったのですが、このとき`AnimationDrawable#setVisible()`が以下のような実装になっているバージョンでは自動再生されるのだと思います。

```
@Override
public boolean setVisible(boolean visible, boolean restart) {
    boolean changed = super.setVisible(visible, restart);
    if (visible) {
        if (changed || restart) {
            setFrame(0, true, true);
        }
    } else {
      unscheduleSelf(this);
    }
    return changed;
}
```

少なくともICEの頃までは`Drawable#setVisible(true, true)`が呼び出されなかったので、古過ぎると発生しません。

現在（5.0.1）の`setVisible()`は以下のような実装になっています。

```
@Override
public boolean setVisible(boolean visible, boolean restart) {
    final boolean changed = super.setVisible(visible, restart);
    if (visible) {
        if (restart || changed) {
            boolean startFromZero = restart || mCurFrame < 0 ||
                    mCurFrame >= mAnimationState.getChildCount();
            setFrame(startFromZero ? 0 : mCurFrame, true, mAnimating);
        }
    } else {
        unscheduleSelf(this);
    }
    return changed;
}
```

`setFrame()`の第三引数でアニメーションするかどうかが決まるのですが、`mAnimating`のフラグで管理することで、必ず`true`を渡してしまうバグを修正しています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。AnimationDrawableが自動的に再生されたのは一部のバージョンのバグだったのですね。こういうバグも頭に入れておきながら作業をしていきたいと思います。大変参考になりました。ありがとうございます。